# Is it possible to use a button to change the text

Tags: rec-room

I have been wanting to have a button that would cycle through text but I have not been able to figure it out. So what I would want to do is that there is one button and when you press that button it will go to message 0 to message 1 and so on and when it gets to message 4 it goes to message 0. I have tried tutorials but they never go over what I have been doing. But if it isn't possible to use a button then what type of circuit do I need to slowly loop the messages. P.S I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do this with CV1 here are the circuits you will need a a (state machine), 5x(states), a (button), and a (text)

First you want to [wire] from the body of one (state) to the (state machine) then [configure] it and name that (state) 0, then wire (state(0) to a new (state) then [configure] your new (state) and name it 1, then wire (state(1) to a new (state) then [configure] your new (state) and name it 2, then wire (state(2) to a new (state) then [configure] your new (state) and name it 3, then wire (state(3) to a new (state) then [configure] your new (state) and name it 4, get you (text) and wire the |light blue| pin to the |red| pin on the (state machine), after that you get your (button) and wire your |red| pin to all the |arrow| pins that are in between watch (state).

Now configurations
(state(0)
R output should be set to {0}
(state(0)
R output should be set to {1}
(state(0)
R output should be set to {2}
(state(0)
R output should be set to {3}
(state(0)
R output should be set to {4}

(text) info

Message 0 in the text will show when (state(0) is active if you don’t know which is active the one that has the symbol on it that is white is the one that is active.

if you need more info just ask :).

-DJ.T

Answer (score 0):

The cv2 "Button" has, at the time of this message, three different cv2 circuits for the button: "Button Get Text", "Button Set Text" and "Button Get Is Pressed".